# Python selenium xpath parse/scrape?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url= 'URL IM REQUESTING XPATH TEXT DATA FROM'

requests = webdriver.Chrome()

requests.get(url)

requests.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="js-post-4426721"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/article/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/pre/code/text()/..').text

print(requests)
```

it only prints the session, not the text that I am requesting to parse/scrape.

> <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="ID")>

Trying to parse/scrape XPATH text from a forum thread.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you're printing your session, not the text. Try:

```
requests = webdriver.Chrome()

requests.get(url)

text = requests.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="js-post-4426721"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/article/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/pre/code/text()/..').text)

print(text)
```

Also, make sure your selector is valid - the /text()/ looks funny to me

Answer (score 1):

i'd say its hard to know exactly unless you specify a forum and at least what you are targetting, so i will offer generic advice:

try using simpler xpath.
Websites nowadays are rendered dynamically, so their classess, or nesting can change relatively fast.

when i do XPATH extractions i try to shorten my XPATH as much as possible, while keeping it relevant.

Also as Oliver pointed - put the line in variable, and than print it

Inspect the code of object you want to target and instead of providing a rather lenghty XPATH:

```
'//*[@id="js-post-4426721"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/article/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/pre/code/text()/..'
```

try something like

```
'//article[@id="exact value of ID"]//div[contains(@class, "partial class attribute value")]/pre/code'
```

if i was to debug the XPATH you provided, i would say its likely an issue to try referencing 'text()'